# Ansible stops connecting to the host via ssh

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

#### Introduction

For over a month I've been running the following command:

```
ansible-playbook -vvvvi host_test rhel-tests.yml
```

Which connected via SSH and ran tests on a host successfully without any problems.
But as of the last couple days, I've received the following when running:

```
fatal: [10.2.16.2]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "unreachable": true
}

MSG:

Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 35742
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Control master terminated unexpectedly
Shared connection to 10.2.16.2 closed.
```

Even though I can establish a normal SSH connection from bash to 10.2.16.2 just fine from the host I'm running.

#### Details

The contents of `host_test` are as follows:

```
[rhel]
10.2.16.2 node_type=xxx

[rhel:vars]
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_method=su
ansible_become_user=root
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=yyy
node_name=""


[cisco]

[cisco:vars]
node_name=""

[curtiss-wright]

[zzz]

[other]

[nmap:children]
rhel
cisco
curtiss-wright
other
zzz

[password-test]
```

Here's my `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
ask_vault_pass = True
filter_plugins = filter_plugins
host_key_checking = False
retry_files_enabled = False
inventory = hosts
stdout_callback = debug

[paramiko_connection]
record_host_keys=False

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o LogLevel=QUIET -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=2m -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
scp_if_ssh = True
```

#### My thoughts

- Configuration changes are happening constantly on the target, so it's possible something was configured in ssh to limit connections in some way.
- Tests are being added to `rhel-tests.yml`, so it's possible some sort of timeout is now being triggered that wasn't before. I've tried reverting back the version of rhel7 to about a month back, and the command still fails, so I believe that this is not likely to be the cause.
- I'm using ansible version 2.5.4 installed via brew. I've tried updating to Ansible 2.6.2, but that seems to have done nothing.
- I've tried several other suggestions found online, including using the `paramiko_ssh` connection type, which also fails.
- I can run `ansible -i hosts_test -m ping 10.2.16.2` and get a pong back
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234911/ansible-ssh-error-during-play) seems pretty close to my issue, but there aren't any lines in `rhel-tests.yml` that reboot or shutdown.

#### Question

*What's causing my playbook to fail and how can I fix it?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The connection may be dropping due to the lack of output from your play.

Add the following to your `ssh_args` ([docs for v2.4](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#ssh-args)) in `ansible.cfg`:

```
-o ServerAliveInterval=50
```

What this `ServerAliveInterval=50` does is keep the ssh connection alive when the play has a lack of output, by the client sending a null packet to the server every 50-seconds.

Comment: see here for what this does: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3027/21256

Comment: Ansible docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-get-ansible-to-notice-a-dead-target-in-a-timely-manner